# HTML- TABLE : one tr on another tr

Tags: html, css, html-table, opacity

I want one `tr` tag on another `tr` tag.

HTML

```
<table width="600" align="center">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td height="10" align="center" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top" align="center" style=" opacity: 0.5; background: #fa4b00 no-repeat;">
            <table width="600" border="0" align="center">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <table width="600" align="center">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td valign="top" align="center" id="1" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; line-height: 30px; letter-spacing:0.5px; text-align:center; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 60px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox" style="font-weight: lighter; font-size: 26px;"> Some Text</span>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the text to be on the top of the background `div`.

[image: want some text to be on top]

Comment: you can nest one table inside of another table... that's what you want to do in here...

Comment: yes... but i have transparent background with opacity. and inside id i have text. but i want text to be top of the background. I can't use div due to HTML Emailers

Comment: Try removing `opacity: 0.5;` from your nested table, and change the background from `#fa4b00` to `rgba(250, 75, 0, .5)`. Specifying the background color as rgba should set opacity on your background only, as opposed to the `opacity` property which sets opacity for the entire element and it's children.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing, one tr on another tr? Could you please clarify what you are having issues with?

Comment: Yes. I want a text to be on top of the background image using `table`. I have given opacity to background image.

Comment: The opacity property applies not only to background but to the whole element. Since you have specified opacity for a `td`, all children of said td will inherit the opacity, including the nested table and all it's contents. Since your text is placed _inside_ the td, it too will end up with 50% opacity. The solution is to use `rgba` for your background(-color) and ditch the opacity property.

Comment: can't use **rgba** , too. As HTML Emailers doesn't support **rgba** color code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not actually sure what are you looking for but if you want to show your text on first  background have a look

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wrap_textbox").clone().appendTo("#top");
});
```

```css
table tr td table tr td .wrap_textbox{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="600" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td height="10" align="center" style="background-color:#f1f1f1;" id="top"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td valign="top" align="center" style=" opacity: 0.5; background: #fa4b00 no-repeat;">

<table width="600" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="600"  align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td valign="top" align="center" id="1" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; line-height: 30px; letter-spacing:0.5px; text-align:center; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 60px;">

<span class="wrap_textbox" style="font-weight: lighter; font-size: 26px;"> Some Text</span>

</td>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</td>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</td>
```

Comment: i can't use third party library. as i can have only HTML , CSS(inline).

Comment: i have the text of other background with this code table tr td table tr td .wrap_textbox{display:none;}

Comment: I am making HTML Emailers , so can't use third party library

Comment: you can try with javascript clone function

Comment: I can't use Javascript. because some of email engines do not support Javascript, external library, Flash etc

Comment: You can't do it with css

Comment: Is there any other way to do so without using JS or Third party library?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty confusing but why not use `<th>` to place the text above like so:

```html
 <table width="600" align="center">
        <tr style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
            <th style="font-weight: lighter; font-size: 26px;">
                Some Text
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center" style=" opacity: 0.5; background: #fa4b00 no-repeat;">
                <table width="600" border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            more text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

You can then adjust the `<th>` style in the CSS to how you want it to be displayed.